# Toast isn't working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, toast, android-toast

I got a common problem, about my Toast does not appearing.
I've searched it on the site many times, and tried some different things. However - it still doesn't work.

My Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Welcome extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText efn,eln,eage;
Button submit;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    efn=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
    eln=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);
    eage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age);

    submit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please complete all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

The xml file of welcome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Welcome" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/welcome_text"
    android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="First name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Last name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lname"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:textDirection="ltr"
    android:inputType="number" />


 <Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
    android:text="Submit" />
```

Instead of `Welcome.this` I've tried also `this` and `getApplicationContext()`.

The result of the code is openning the screen and after pressing the button - nothing happend.

I have no other option.. therefore I ask you guys for help.

Thanks in advance,

Yaniv.

The error log according to @jmsalcido answer:

```
01-25 17:57:07.367: D/gralloc_goldfish(3248): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-25 17:57:08.387: I/Choreographer(3248): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-25 17:57:08.768: D/AndroidRuntime(3248): Shutting down VM
01-25 17:57:08.768: W/dalvikvm(3248): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method showToast(View) in the activity class com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'submit'
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showToast [class android.view.View]
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
01-25 17:57:08.798: E/AndroidRuntime(3248):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post R.layout.activity_welcome.

Comment: Where is your closing Class bracket (**}**)?

Comment: why show a Toast with application context instead of activity context?!

Comment: He says he tried. I am assuming that he probably set the `onClick=` attribute in xml.

Comment: try to remove the activity and create it again !! 
because there is really nothing wrong with your code .

Comment: I did run it several times. Nothing changed.

Comment: What I mean is, please post the xml file where you define the layout for your `Activity`.

Comment: either set onClick attribute in your xml or implement onClickListener for button. Show your activity_welcom xml code, only then error can be found out. Otherwise your code is fine to work with.

Comment: there is no error in your code..clean the project and try to run.

Comment: See this answer..if it works..http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170051/2035885

Comment: Tried it before, and now also.
Still nothing :\

Comment: @YanivGK Is this all your code ? Because I ran this on my system and it is working fine.

Comment: No it's only part on it..

Comment: Are you testing with an emulator?

Comment: Yes, and I've checked the checkbox of "show notifications", if this what you thought of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a simulator or running it in a device?

Nothing seems wrong but try if this works for you, its the same but instead of implementing OnClickListener and the override try this

```
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please complete all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });
```

and leave the class like this

```
public class Welcome extends Activity
```

and remove

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please complete all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Doesn't work either :/
The button just do nothing.

The log shows that:
01-25 18:02:48.467: E/Trace(3429): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-25 18:02:49.367: I/Choreographer(3429): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-25 18:02:49.427: D/gralloc_goldfish(3429): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-25 18:02:50.424: I/Choreographer(3429): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: I cleaned the project and start over. It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok great! Yes, sometimes eclipse and java can be tedious to work with, and you just have to clean and build everything to solve some issues!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this check in `OnClick`

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.submit) {
  Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "Please complete all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

When you implement an `OnClickListener`, the `onClick()` method consumes a `View`. When performing any actions in the `onClick()`, we need to check on which `View` is it called on. In a case where there may be more than one button (or more than one view to click on), this helps identify on what `View` are we calling the onCLick on. Hence the check `if (v.getId() == R.id.submit)` is important.

Comment: I understand it's importance, however right now the app stopped right after pressing the button.

Comment: I take it back. The app doesn't stop, just do nothing after the pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Difference between Activity Context and Application Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128589/difference-between-activity-context-and-application-context) you should use Activity.this not getApplicationContext()

Comment: I've read it, and tried to use it. As I have written in the question.

Comment: I see that it is written there, but others that read this should see the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

always go to developers.android.com: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#ClickListener

do not Override the onClick method, use an onClick listener there, this should work, this is your actual file:

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/submit"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
  android:text="Submit" />
```

add an android:onClick attribute there to look like this:

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/submit"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
  android:onClick="showToast"
  android:text="Submit" />
```

and in your Activity:

```
public void showToast(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please complete all the details", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: After I'm doing so and press the button, The app stopped to work.

Comment: oh yeah use getApplicationContext not Welcome.this if it is not working, please share the log.

Comment: yeah please show me the log because this is working: look at the image http://i.imgur.com/yuLCiBi.png

Comment: according your log posted: `Could not find a method showToast(View) in the activity class com.example.idiagnostician1.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'submit'` :: there is no method in your MainActivity.java named showToast

Comment: What does it means? and how should I fix it?

Comment: Amm I'm running the Welcome.class right after the Main_Activity. So it skips that.

Comment: I run it directly now and somehow it worked, Thanks.